# Flutter Sum values in a list

Tags: flutter

How to sum the values with the same month?

I have this list from realtime database:

```
I/flutter (10602): {Valor: 10, Date: 2021-Jan-20, IndicadorRef: Filmes}

I/flutter (10602): {Valor: 20, Date: 2021-Feb-20, IndicadorRef: Filmes}

I/flutter (10602): {Valor: 30, Date: 2021-Mar-20, IndicadorRef: Filmes}

I/flutter (10602): {Valor: 5, Date: 2021-Abr-20, IndicadorRef: Filmes}

I/flutter (10602): {Valor: 8, Date: 2021-Mai-20, IndicadorRef: Filmes}

I/flutter (10602): {Valor: 10, Date: 2021-Jun-20, IndicadorRef: Filmes}

I/flutter (10602): {Valor: 15, Date: 2021-Jul-20, IndicadorRef: Filmes}

I/flutter (10602): {Valor: 23, Date: 2021-Aug-20, IndicadorRef: Filmes}

I/flutter (10602): {Valor: 43, Date: 2021-Aug-31, IndicadorRef: Filmes}

I/flutter (10602): {Valor: 33, Date: 2021-Set-20, IndicadorRef: Filmes}

I/flutter (10602): {Valor: 22, Date: 2021-Out-20, IndicadorRef: Filmes}

I/flutter (10602): {Valor: 10, Date: 2021-Nov-20, IndicadorRef: Filmes}

I/flutter (10602): {Valor: 2, Date: 2021-Dez-20, IndicadorRef: Filmes}
```

I want to sum the values that have the same month, like Aug.

This is where I can get this list:

```
getData() async {
_database.child("Dados").onValue.listen((event) {
  dataValues.clear();
  temporaryDataValues.clear();
  finalDataValues.clear();

  var keys = event.snapshot.value.keys;

  var values = event.snapshot.value;

  for (var key in keys) {
    Data data = new Data(
      values[key]["Valor"],
      values[key]["Date"],
      values[key]["IndicadorRef"],
    );



    if (data.indicadorRef == AreaScreen.indicadores[AreaScreen.indicadorIndex].name) {
      print(data.toJson().toString());
      dataValues.add(data);
      temporaryDataValues.add(data.valor);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand the question, but I assume Data is a class you defined that stores the value as an int, the date as a DateTime, and the indicadorRef as something else?

If so, in order to make a list of all data you would do something like this:

```dart
List<Data> data = keys.map((key) => Data(
      values[key]["Valor"],
      values[key]["Date"],
      values[key]["IndicadorRef"], // I'd make these named parameters if I were you
    )).toList();
```

then to get all values in a given month:

```
int month = DateTime.april // whatever month you want
//int month = DateTime.now().month; // in case you want the current month

List<Data> sameMonth = data.where((current) => current.date.month == month).toList();
```

finally to add all values:

```dart
int value = sameMonth.fold<int>(0, (prev, curr) => pre+curr.valor);
```

and if you wanted to do all of that at the same time:

```
int value = keys.map((key) => Data(
      values[key]["Valor"],
      values[key]["Date"],
      values[key]["IndicadorRef"],
    ))
    .where((current) => current.date.month == month)
    .fold<int>(0, (prev, curr) => prev + curr.valor);
```

I hope that answered your question